# Curve without changing position of end vertices

Tags: bezier-curves

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days (on and off), I am hoping someone can help me solve this.

I want to create an arc (curve) that will not change the position of the start and end vertices.  In the image below, shows the pre modification of my line.  The start and end vertices marked with empty's.  I want to arc this line towards the 3rd empty.

[image: Img 1]

The second image is what is happening when I add a simple deform (bend).  As you can see, then end vertices move (this is what I want to prevent)

[image: Img 2]

If there is another solution other than simple deform (Maybe some type of curve?), that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly every modifier has a "Vertex group" field, in which you can limit the action to vertices belonging to that vertex group only (or the opposite, using the double arrow icon).

As the vertex are weighted to the vertex group, the effect can be fine tuned for smooth transitions.

In my example I used a limited Lattice modifier.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was using vertex groups, but with your help it was the exclude that did the trick, thanks for the help.